# woocommerce - get category image from mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to return my categories images from mysql database in woocommerce . I don't know what should I do and How can I return the images from database.

so far I just return categories names and Ides ,

```
SELECT * from `wp_terms` where term_id in (SELECT term_id FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` WHERE `taxonomy` LIKE 'product_cat' AND `parent` = 0 and count>0)
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try below code:

    $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC'));
    foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) :
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catTerm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
    // get the image URL
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
    <li>
        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="152" height="245"/>
        <span><?php echo $catTerm->name; ?></span>
    </li>
    endforeach;
```

Comment: thanks for reply , a question , I have an empty php page , What should I include in my page to access these classes and functions ?

Comment: you can use this code by create custom template page from empty page.Accept answer if it is useful.

Comment: thanks for reply, could you give me an example ,How can I do so ?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Answer (score 0):

To display the category image for the currently displayed category  -

```
// verify that this is a product category page
if ( is_product_category() ){
    global $wp_query;

    // get the query object
    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    // get the thumbnail id using the queried category term_id
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

    // get the image URL
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 

    // print the IMG HTML
    echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='' width='762' height='365' />";
}
```